# No message body writer has been found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I am trying to create a *JAX-RS* resource that must produce *JSON* data.

I am running on *Apache TomEE 9.0.0-M7* and *Jakarta Web Profile 9.1*.

Calling `getPrincipals` on the `PrincipalResource` class produces the error below.

Why I am getting a `java.util.Vector` error when the `getPrincipal` method returns a `List`?

Please assist.

> Mar 05, 2022 10:06:57 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils
> logMessageHandlerProblem SEVERE: No message body writer has been found
> for class java.util.Vector, ContentType: application/json

**Get method**

```
@Path("/principal")
public class PrincipalResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Principal> getPrincipals() {
        AccessControl accessControl = new AccessControl();
        return accessControl.findPrincipals();
    }
}
```

**Principal class**

```
public class Principal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "principalNumber")
    private long principalNumber;

    @Pattern(regex = Regex.EMAIL, message = "Invlid email address")
    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Pattern(regex = Regex.FIRST_NAME, message = "Invlid first name")
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Pattern(regex = Regex.LAST_NAME, message = "Invlid last name")
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Pattern(regex = Regex.PASSWORD, message = "Invlid password.")
    @Column(name = "principalPassword")
    private String principalPassword;

    @Column(name = "activated")
    private boolean activated;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "principal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @XmlTransient
    private List<PrincipalRole> principalRoles;

    public Principal() {
    }
```

**Maven**

```
        <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                                        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
                                        <version>9.1.0</version>
                                        <scope>provided</scope>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                                        <groupId>za.co.ezimax</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.0.1</version>
                        </dependency>                               
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In particular, could you please provide the implementation of the `Principal` class and the related classes?

Comment: Additionally, in particular, could you please provide the content of the Maven project file (`pom.xml`)?

Comment: It is to be assumed, that the class `Principal` owns a field of type `Vector`.

Comment: I never use the Vector class anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The object (Vector) you are returning is not serializable by the default JAXRS implementation.
You need to provide a serializable DTO as the return value.

Comment: List is an interface. The actual implementation returned by `AccessControl` is a concrete class (`Vector`).  The serializer is looking for the concrete instance, thus it's trying to serialize `Vector`.

Comment: I have checked the AccessControl class. The class does not return any Vector. In fact, I never use the Vector class in any of my code.